# Is adoptable storage in any new android version (9,10,11) original?

Tags: internal-storage, adoptable-storage

**Question Is adoptable storage in any  new android version (9,10,11) original ?**

I am planning to purchase new smart phone mobile for video editing graphic editing game apps. I want to install aprrox 200-400 apps as file in video editing are huge so I want to use app from external micro sd card and save output and files.on high speed v30 u30 160mbps/90mbps micro sd external card

As new mobile within warranty  so don't  want to root and use link2sd or app2sd apps to.lapse void  warranty

In **android 5.1.1 lolipop** there was option to move partly files to sd card by  android llolipop native app2sd option settings>apps>app info **"Move to sd card"**

In **android 6.0 marshemellow** the option of **adoptable storage** to   which formats the external micro sd card as internal memory

In **android 7.1** there is option in settings developer option  **"Force app to SD"**

In **android 8,9,10,11 or 9 pie** I don't what alternative option given  there in below  findings it say it have  the option hidden and activated by **SM (storage manager) command** . Is there any way to get adoptable storage
( Formatting  external micro sd as internal)  or move app to sd (android native app2sd) or  developer option (force app to sd)

But as samsung galaxy have removed all adoptable storage option form its galaxy smart phone but planning to start with android pie 9.0

Can any one suggest me which android OS 9 11.0 or android 10.0 or android 12.0 can support  adoptable storage without rooting

**Some.findings**
https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable

https://www.quora.com/Which-Smartphones-use-adoptable-storage

https://www.sammobile.com/2018/11/13/samsung-android-pie-adoptable-storage-feature

Comment: Sorry, but device recommendation is off-topic here. You might be interested in our sister site, Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange, but please ensure to follow [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) to get the best device for your need.

Comment: @Andrew T. Bro thanx for reminding anad managing soory I didn't knew ...any other  stack exchange forums for find recommendation mobile hardware...as in have once did in computer hardware and mobile is off topic there to...a personal  suggestion  feedback as a administrator u  should recommend to move the topic to other sub site then closing or deleting topic thread..as closing long type question some users may get upset

Comment: @Andrew T. Bro as my question is for android's adoptable storage  technical  feature on OS based opinion solution not only Ram  ROM or device ..I think it's miisnderstood

Comment: Sorry, the community has decided that device/brand recommendation is off-topic here. Also, Android device recommendations are [generally on-topic on HardwareRecs.SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android), but we generally don't migrate questions if we are not sure if the question as-is written will be on-topic or not. Though, probably they don't accept broad questions like brand, instead of specific devices. If that's the case, then there's no Stack Exchange sites that may be appropriate. You can try other sites like XDA Forums, Reddit, or Quora though.

Comment: @Andrew T. Bro i have edited see if satisfy and matches to the rules protocols of stack exchange .. if u think u can help to edit urself if one or two words alterations matches protocols ..but my suggestion that the more we discuss in a community with problems the more Reasearch and development increases..the protocols rules is good to manage mob but it to ties bind the more  people interacts in forums there  and chance of more intakes opinions and some.opinions suggestion hits to more discoveries.. that's why R&D..standards few protocols are good to controlbut all should be open minded ..

Comment: Your edit was appropriate, so I decided to reopen it. Note that Stack Exchange is a strict objective/factual Q&A, thus opinions are generally *discouraged*. No hard feeling, but that's just what the Stack Exchange Q&A model is. If you want more open-ended discussions/opinions, then SE is really not the best site for this, and there are other sites out there that are more appropriate for this, like XDA Forums and Reddits.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while searching for a problem dealing with adoptable storage. While not a direct answer about adoptable storage, I know it's typically used to gain space on internal storage and wanted to note the alternative: "Force allow apps on external" still exists under developer options (close to the bottom). At least it exists in Android 11 on a Samsung A01. Once I got adoptable storage cleaned up/removed, I enabled it and was then able to move a few GB of apps/data to the SD card making the phone more usable again.

Comment: you got adoptable-storage working on Samsung device? sure it is One UI?

Comment: I'm not sure. I followed instructions [here](https://jimcofer.com/2016/03/10/marshmallow-lg-and-adoptable-storage/). Seemed to work in Android 10 (one screen in settings showed 80GB of storage and I could move some apps to the card). It freed enough space to update the OS to 11 and afterwards it basically crashed until I removed the SD-card. I then had to figure out how to undo adoptable storage and then tried again and it didn't work - always just showed 16GB in storage and while it gave me the option to move apps, it failed. Finally found the setting to force apps to SD which works OK-ish.