# I have a Samsung A51 android smartphone, how can I adopt my SD card as internal storage

Tags: sd-card

On my A51 android smartphone how can I adopt my SD card to internal storage.

Comment: you can't as this feature is not supported by Samsung https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241909